# Why is a solution to $y'' + y = 0$ periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symmetry

Solutions to $y'' + y = 0$ are 2$\pi$ periodic. Is this accidental or does this ODE have some symmetries associated with it that force the solutions to be periodic?

Comment: One point you can note is that it conserves the quantity $y'^2/2+y^2/2$ so the trajectories are confined to this circle in phase space. Moreover the problem is autonomous and has unique solutions, so the system can't wobble back and forth around the circle, it can only spiral around it. I can't think of much else that is as explicit as that except for explicit solutions to the whole problem. Even something like Floquet theory really works by *reducing* the problem to one like this.

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial is $$\lambda ^2+1=0, \lambda = \pm i$$ which implies the solutions are $$y=c_1 \cos(t)+c_2 \sin(t)$$

Thus the solutions are periodic with period $2\pi$

You may also check the phase plane of the system $$ y'=u,u'=-y$$ which implies $$y^2+u^2=C$$ hence the solutions are periodic.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the equation $y'' + y = 0$ it conserves the quantity $y'^2/2+y^2/2$, so the trajectories are confined to this circle in phase space. Moreover, the equation is autonomous and has unique solutions, so the system can't wobble back and forth around the circle; it can only spiral around it. This is almost sufficient to show that any solution must be periodic; I think it only remains to show that the system continues moving at a rate which is bounded below by a positive number, rather than approaching a steady state.

(Answer based on a comment by [Ian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83396/Ian).)

Comment: It just needs to complete a period in finite time and then you get the bound you need. Perhaps you can compute $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=1$, where $\theta$ is the argument of the state in phase space? That's getting awfully close to an explicit solution, though.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of framing this in a more group theoretical language. E.g. can I show that the ODE invariant under some group action?

Comment: @Bondo There's a bunch of algebra associated to Hamiltonian dynamics but it's mostly in Lie theory.